# cannot apply sed to the stdout within a docker image

Tags: docker, sed, s2i

I have a docker file that has an entry point which is an s2i/bin/run script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export_vars=$(cgroup-limits); export $export_vars

exec /opt/app-root/services.sh
```

The `services.sh` script runs php-fpm and nginx:

```
php-fpm 2>&1
nginx -c /opt/app-root/etc/conf.d/nginx/nginx.conf
# this echo to stdout is needed otherwise no stdout doesn't show up on the docker run output
echo date 2>&1
```

The php scripts are logging to `stderr` so that script does `2>&1` to redirected to `stdout` which is needed for the log aggregator.

I want to run `sed` or `awk` over the log output. Yet if I try:

```
php-fpm 2>&1 | sed 's/A/B/g'
```

or

```
exec /opt/app-root/services.sh | sed 's/A/B/g'
```

Then nothing shows up when I run the container. Without the pipe to sed the output of `php-fpm` shows up as the output of `docker run` okay.

Is there a way to `sed` the output of `php-fpm` ensuring that the output makes it to the output of docker?

*Edit* Note that I tried the obvious `| sed 's/A/B/g'` in *both* places and was also trying running the pipe in a subshell `$(stuff|sed 's/A/B/g')` in *both* places. Neither works so this seems to be a `Docker` or `s2i` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping sed arguments in double quotes.

php-fpm 2>&1 | sed "s/A/B/g"

Comment: The question says that I tried that and that it doesn't work.

Comment: I have seen some cases single quote didn't give us exact output inside shell script, so asked to try keep  double quotes  (") .